# adblock hiding the social login button

Tags: html, social-networking, adblock

In my webapp i am using social network login buttons, which looks like:

```
<a class="logo-fb social-icon" href="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=******&amp;scope=public_profile,email&amp;redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&amp;state=facebook"></a>
```

However, **adblock version 2.4.5** with parameters **Antisocial Filter List** or **Fanboy's Annoyances** enabled hides these buttons and makes login impossible. Is where any way to avoid this blocking or disabling adblock is the only option? Thanks in advance.

Full page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=0">
        <meta name="description"
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quiz-layout.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-styles.css">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/fira-sans-300.400.700.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/merriweather-sans-400.700.800.css'>
        <noscript>
            <style>html{display:none;}</style>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.0;url=nojs">
        </noscript>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="login" method="post"
          id="login">
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="flex row">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="/" class="logo-menu"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-green-small-inactive">
                        <h6 class="white">30:00</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="head">
                    <p>Login with:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="social-login">
                    <a class="logo-fb social-icon"
                       href=https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=*&scope=public_profile,email&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&state=facebook></a>
                    <a class="logo-in social-icon"
href=https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=*&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&state=linkedin> </a>
                    <a class="logo-vk social-icon"
                       href=https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=*&response_type=code&display=page&v=5.37&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&scope=email&state=vk> </a>
                    <a class="logo-gplus social-icon"
                       href=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?&approval_prompt=auto&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&client_id=*&state=gplus> </a>
                    <a class="logo-git social-icon"
                       href=https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&client_id=*&scope=user:email&state=github> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="decoration">
            <div class="test-decorations">
                <div class="title-decoration animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-1 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-2 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-3 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-4 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="answer-decoration green animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="title-decoration animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-1 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-2 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-3 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-4 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="answer-decoration green animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="title-decoration animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-1 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-2 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-3 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-4 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="answer-decoration green animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="title-decoration animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-1 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-2 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-3 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="line-decoration-4 animated fadeIn"></div>
                <div class="answer-decoration green animated fadeIn"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please, share the full code for the login page.